# Resource id #4 PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT indvsum.sum1 + indvsum.sum2
    FROM (SELECT SUM(Cash) AS sum1,
                 SUM(Bank) AS sum2
          FROM players) indvsum");

    echo $result;
```

For some reason this is returning Resource id #4.

How do I get the results of sum1 + sum2 returned?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.

Please check out the manual for some example about how to fetch rows:

[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

This is the signature:

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

For getting the rows you should use

[mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

or

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

for example.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the standard output of mysql_query function. It returns the identifier related to that query.
To get selected rows use mysql_fetch_array($result) or mysql_fetch_row($result)

Answer (score 1):

Resource id #4 is being returned because **`$result`** is an array.

As an example:

```
$q_example = "SELECT indvsum.sum1 + indvsum.sum2 AS `aSUM`
                  FROM (SELECT SUM(Cash) AS sum1, SUM(Bank) AS sum2 FROM players) indvsum";
$rsexample = mysql_query($q_example, $DB) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsexample = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsexample);

echo $row_rsexample['aSUM'];
```

...should get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just do

```
SELECT SUM(Cash) AS sum1,
       SUM(Bank) AS sum2
FROM players;
```

Assign the two values in php and then add them.

or

Use `mysql_fetch_row`

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_array`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT indvsum.sum1 + indvsum.sum2
FROM (SELECT SUM(Cash) AS sum1,
             SUM(Bank) AS sum2
      FROM players) indvsum");

$arr = mysql_fetch_array($result);

print_r($arr); // echo $result;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$values = mysql_fetch_array($result);                      
var_dump($values);
```

Comment: A code dump with no additional information is not helpful to anyone. Please strive to make your future answers more useful.