# resource id #4 mysql error Why am I getting this?

Tags: php, mysql

My code looks like this:

```
$var_check_user = 'SELECT * FROM shipperregister WHERE ID=1 AND username="saeeduddin"';
echo $insert = mysql_query($var_check_user, $var_connection);
```

On resulting page I see output:

```
resource id #4
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use mysql functions as it is deprecated. switch to MYSQLI or PDO

Comment: Please refer to this link might be of help: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704670/resource-id-4-php-mysql)!

Comment: you do not fetch anything here. use mysql_fetch_assoc.. What you get is the standard output.

Comment: you clearly need more tutorials on db connection. Check http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Answer (score 0):

From PHP docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.

So, if you try echo resource, this converts to string like `resource id #N`